# Understanding how JPA 2.0 Cache updates

Tags: database, caching, jpa

I have a JPA entity with the following definition. Its marked as read only and the cache is set to expire at 3 am.

Please consider this scenario . 
1. The table has a record with deptId :100 and department Name: "SALES"

1. Fetch the record programatically using

   ```
   entityManager.createNamedQuery("Department.findById").setParameter("depId",100)           .getResultList();
   ```

The returned record contains the department name as "SALES"

1. The above record data is modified directly in the backend database using a update 
   sqlquery. changed the department name from "SALES" to "REGIONAL_SALES"
2. Programatically fetch the record with deptId :100 using      `entityManager.createNamedQuery("Department.findById").setParameter("depId",100)           .getResultList();`
3. The returned record contains the updated department name

How does JPA know the value in the backend has been updated? Instead of fetching from cache its fetching the updated value from DB

or

Is it the cache got updated after the DB change. I  have set the cache to expire only at 3am (24 hr format)

Please help me understand

```
@NamedQuery(name="Department.findById", query = "SELECT d from Department d WHERE d.deptNo= :depId")
@Entity
@Table(name="DEPARTMENT")
@Cache(expiryTimeOfDay=@TimeOfDay(hour=3))
@ReadOnly

public class Department{
@EmbeddedId 
int deptNo;

@Column
String deptName;

//constructor, getter and setter

}
```

Comment: "JPA" doesn't know anything, it's an interface. Perhaps mentioning your JPA implementation, and what is your L2 cache type may help people answer the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA providers have different caching policies. You didn't state what provider do you use but I'm assuming that you are using EclipseLink. Quote from their wiki:

> By default in EclipseLink all queries access the database, unless they are by Id, or by cache indexed fields.

I recommend you check

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching/Query_Cache
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.6/concepts/cache003.htm

From my point of view your query should hit cache first.
Its strange though you annotate `@EmbeddedId` and `int` typed field. 
Does it work for you because it causes following exception?

> The Entity class (...) has an embedded at
>   tribute [id] of type [class int] which is NOT an Embeddable class. Probable reason: missing @Embeddable or missing  in orm.xml if metadata-complete

Comment: Yes am using eclipse link. The @EmbeddedId is a typo mistake and actually am using a class fro the primary key.

Comment: The point i take from your post is if query is based on an id (primary key), the cache will be checked first.  If the query is not based on the primary key or is based on a part of primary key where there is a chance of multiple rows returned , then the query will hit the database

Answer (score 0):

A query will go to the database (barring any implementation-specific option to just use the cache). It isn't a case of the implementation "knowing" the datastore is updated ... it goes there anyway. Not the same for a `EM.find()` call though.